# Resizing IText pdf so the text fits on one page

Tags: java, pdf, resize, itext

I'm working with a label printer which prints my pdf file. I create the file like this:

```
public static Document createPDF() {
float pageWidth = 176f;
    float pageHeight = 200f;

    Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(pageWidth, pageHeight);
    Document document = new Document(pageSize);
    document.setMargins(5, 5, 1, 0);
    String file = MainActivity.FILE_URI;
    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return document;
}
```

Then I add some paragraphs to it. The paragraphs have variabel length. When I exceed the length of the page IText adds another page. The pages are 62 x 75 mm.

I want to change the length based on the amount of text so I don't waste paper. I tried this:

```
try {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(MainActivity.FILE_URI);

    while (reader.getNumberOfPages() > 1) {
        float pageHeight = document.getPageSize().getHeight();
        float pageWidth = document.getPageSize().getWidth();

        pageHeight += 50f;

        document.setPageSize(new Rectangle(pageWidth, pageHeight));
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it's not working. The pages aren't getting longer so the number of pages stays the same and causes a loop.

Anyone knows a solution?

Comment: do you want to change the size of the printed text to be evenly distributed over the number of available pages, or do you want to change the paper on which you print to the correct size (with a printer that supports this)?

Comment: Good question. I can't answer the OP without the answer to this counter-question!

Comment: stretch the paper. the printer has a 10 meter roll so I can print any length

Comment: Essentially you need to first draw on a very long page, longer than any plausible input to your use case, and then cut off the lower, empty parts.

Comment: I understand that, but how would I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you need to first draw on a very long page, longer than any plausible input to your use case, and then cut off the lower, empty parts.

This means that you have to start by setting your `pageHeight` value accordingly. A safe value is

```
float pageHeight = 14400f;
```

The result you get now is a PDF document with one extremely long page, more than 5m in length.

This page has to be shortened to match the contents. This can be done in a second pass like this (I use the `pageSize` rectangle you have already defined; INTERMEDIATE points to the PDF you generated in the first pass):

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(INTERMEDIATE);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, FINAL_RESULT);

PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
TextMarginFinder finder = parser.processContent(1, new TextMarginFinder());

PdfDictionary page = reader.getPageN(1);
page.put(PdfName.CROPBOX, new PdfArray(new float[]{pageSize.getLeft(), finder.getLly(), pageSize.getRight(), pageSize.getTop()}));
stamper.markUsed(page);

stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

Depending on your document data you can keep the intermediary PDF in memory by using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` for your `PdfWriter`, retrieving the intermdeiate PDF as `byte[]` after `document.close()`, and feeding that `byte[]` into the `PdfReader` in the second step.

Comment: The `TextMarginFinder` demands resources you may not need. As you have control over the creation process, you can get the Y position (telling you how much space is needed) during the creation phase. You can either use the `PdfWriter.getVerticalPosition()` method, or you can add the content using the `ColumnText` object and ask the final Y position with the `getYLine()` method. You can also create the PDF in one go, by creating a `PdfTemplate` with an extreme height, add the content to this `PdfTemplate` using `ColumnText` and then add a clipped `PdfTemplate` to a page of the right size.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie You are completely right. Having seen that the `Document` creation in the OP's code was factored into a method of its own, I merely tried to show the way requiring as little special attention by the caller as possible.

Comment: I know but I'll test it first :) I'm having some nexus 7 driver problem which I have to solve first

Comment: @ButterBeast As the solution worked for the OP, there seems to be an important difference between your case and his case. Thus, you should create a new question in which you describe your case in enough detail that the difference may be spotted.